# opening activity only once NOT WORKING

Tags: android, android-activity

i followed some other questions on stack overflow and created a basic project to open an activity only once.However its not working.what wrong?
After opening once, i close it. However on reopening it starts with the first activity again.

my first activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class));
        }
    });
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF",    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)){

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
        ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
        ed.commit();
    }
}
}
```

my second activity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it, hope it helps:

First activity inside `onCreate`

```
if (pref.getString("someConstant",null) == null){
    //This is my first time, no value in sharedpref for "someConstant"
    //Feel free to do any logic here if needed
}else{
    //not my first time
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();   
}
```

Now in your second activity, once it opens just set the shared preference inside `onCreate`

```
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
ed.putString("someConstant","some random string, does not make difference").commit();
```

On first start your app won't have any value, therefore it will stay in the first activity because "someConstant" returns `null`. Once you enter the second activity the value in shared preferences will be stored, so in any new app launch after that you will go straight to the second activity

Comment: i used your code, now it just goes to the second activity first time itself.can you please post your java files

Comment: Let me know if I got your problem right: You want the app to launch only one time that activity and never launch it again, or in every launch, you want to launch it once, and never again in that launch?

Comment: I am doing a verification page ..so yeah once the user is verified no need to open the page ever.

Comment: Then, that code should suffice. Don't forget to uninstall the app before you test it

Comment: Got it working..thanks .Turns out i need to manually uninstall the app before installing it. Reinstalling on the previous version doesn't work.Don't know how it on on emulator though.

Comment: Yes that's right, you need to uninstall the app in order to clear the data from the application, i.e., the shared preferences. In the emulator is pretty much the same, long press with your mouse on the app icon, and uninstall :)

Answer (score 1):

change your code . save first then open activity .

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
        ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
        ed.commit();
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```